# Azure DevOps yaml branch validation pipeline for branch wildcard naming policy

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, pull-request, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

We are in the process of configuring a git branching strategy where we want to trigger PR validation pipeline when a PR is created on increment/* branch after our changes are made in various feature branches and are ready to be integrated into an 'increment' that will be shipped, thus the name. Azure DevOps allows wildcard branch policies at the project level so that you can apply policies to all future branches using that policy naming convention, but how do we apply this same convention to each of several Azure git Repos we have their own pipelines in?

Having to create a new branch policy for every single branch matching our increment/* breaks the convenience of being able to set policies based on branch pattern conventions. Is there a work around for this or have they fixed this in newer releases?

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2.

I am not even sure what to try here. I am a little confused since I believe you can accomplish this behavior using pr triggers in the YAML, but that only works for GitHub repositories; it makes no sense to leave this feature out of your core product (especially one you are selling on-premises instance of).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you can do this by creating a branch matching the policy for the repo, going to that repo's policies and clicking on the folder instead of a branch. It automatically goes to the policy screen for *your branch*/*. I did not find this documented, but I finally thought to click that and it worked.

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru2e5.png) [screeshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxbHE.png) [screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsb63.png)